# Born in "year" ?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if: Born in 1996 < for example is a right form? or there is something else instead of "in" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/born-in-born-on.303175/?hl=es) website (see fenixpollo's answer):

> Born **in**:
>
> - born in + year — *I was born in 1980.*
> - born in + month — *I was born in October.*
> - born in + place — *I was born in Guadalajara.*
>
> Born **on:**
>
> - born on + day — *I was born on Saturday.*
> - born on + date — *I was born on the 4th of July.*

Comment: "in" is used when there are multiple days in the timeline you're referring to such as the year, the month, the week, etc. "on" if you're referring to a specific day.