# Indicating all the date details

Tags: prepositions

I have a problem with the preposition that I have to use before indicating the date detail such:

The 3 th March 2016 .Is it correct when We use the preposition " at" before this date or other prepositions such as: on,in....

Which one is correct, for instance in this example:

I Will come to France at the 3th March 2016. Is this sentence correct with preposition "at"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Born in “year” ?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299181/born-in-year)

Comment: While my family is used to me saying "oneth", "tooth", and "threeth" for ordinals, you'd probably be better served if you used "first" ("1st"), "second" ("2nd"), and "third" ("3rd").

Answer (score 2):

The correct preposition is "on" if that is the date you will arrive.  Also, it's 3rd March, not 3th March.